# Disable client-side browser caching for specific page

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a specific page in a WordPress site that I want to disable client-side browser caching for.

I found a plugin (https://wordpress.org/plugins/prevent-browser-caching/) but we want to avoid adding unnecessary plugins for maintenance / security reasons.

I also found a way to do this with HTTP headers ([How do we control web page caching, across all browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/how-do-we-control-web-page-caching-across-all-browsers)) but by the time WordPress is rendering the page, it's too late to manipulate the headers.

I am doing this custom PHP, but it gets stuck in an infinite loop... thoughts?

```
if ($department == "xxxxxxxxxx" && time() - $_GET['nocache'] > 1) {
  echo time() - $_GET['nocache'];
?>

  <html>
  <body>
  <script>
    var curr_page = window.location.href,
    next_page = "";
    next_page = curr_page + "?nocache=" + <?= time()?>;
    window.location = next_page;
  </script>
  </body>
  </html>

  <?php
  die();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
if ($department == "xxxxx" && time() - $_GET['nocache'] > 900) {
?>

  <html>
  <body>
  <script>
    var curr_page = window.location.pathname,
    next_page = "";
    next_page = curr_page + "?nocache=" + <?= time() ?>;
    window.location = next_page;
  </script>
  </body>
  </html>

  <?php

  die();

}
```

Comment: is this an answer or did you just copy the code from the post?

Comment: This is the answer.